# MVC Gridview sort arrow change color

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

In MVCxGridView how can I change the color of the small arrow that sorts ascending/descending on the right side of the header?

http://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/GroupingSorting/Sorting

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this is going to be something that is easily changed as the arrows themselves are actually `<img>` elements that point to sprites defined by the theme being used :

```
.literally-tons-of-other-styles-here,
.dxGridView_gvDetailExpandedButton_Metropolis, 
.dxgvFocusedRow_Metropolis .dxGridView_gvDetailExpandedButtonRtl_Metropolis{
    background-image: url('/MVCxGridViewDemos/DXR.axd?r=0_1659-NDGyc');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Either you would need to explicitly override this by using your own image and targeting the proper styles or determine if there is another theme that better suits your needs using something like :

```
.dxGridView_gvHeaderSortUp_Metropolis {
     background-image: url('your-custom-arrow-url-here')!important;
}
```

Comment: Where would I override this to use my own image?

Comment: I provided a very basic example, which would be somewhat of a way to handle it. You would likelywise need a style called `.dxGridView_gvHeaderSortDown_Metropolis` to handle your other direction.

Comment: Sorry for the questions. Where would I call this method?  .dxGridView_gvHeaderSortUp_Metropolis {
     background-image: url('your-custom-arrow-url-here')!important;
}

Comment: This would be a CSS style defined within a `.css` file that is referenced in your application. This would be a purely client-side change.

Comment: But how do you reference it? Where would I define .dxGridView_gvHeaderSortUp_Metropolis ? Thank you so much